# Can't change ActiveMQ redeliveryPolicy

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

We're using ActiveMQ 5.14.2.1 triggered by the [Java Windows service wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html), accessing from a Tomcat webapp using JMS and the Spring framework JMS (v4.3.28).

I'm trying to configure a redelivery policy so that when we return the message to the queue using `session.rollback()` it follows the policy. To do this, I set up the `redeliveryPlugin` in the `activemq.xml` file as follows:

```xml
<amq:redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
    <amq:redeliveryPolicyMap>
        <amq:redeliveryPolicyMap>
            <amq:defaultEntry>
                <amq:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="20" useExponentialBackOff="true" 
initialRedeliveryDelay="1000" redeliveryDelay="2000" maximumRedeliveryDelay="600000"/>
            </amq:defaultEntry>
        </amq:redeliveryPolicyMap>
    </amq:redeliveryPolicyMap>
</amq:redeliveryPlugin>
```

I also updated the broker element to turn on schedulerSupport:

```xml
<amq:broker brokerName="MyBroker" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" 
            useJmx="false" schedulerSupport="true">
```

I've tried a few permutations of this based on various [documentation pages](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy) and [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333078/how-to-set-the-activemq-redeliverypolicy-on-a-queue) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102251/how-to-turn-on-schedulersupport-in-tomee-activemq) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828395/activemq-broker-redeliveryplugin-configuration-not-working-for-topic), without success. Whatever I try it's using the default redelivery behavior (1 second between, no exponential backoff, max of 6 retries). I know it's reading this `activemq.xml` file, because when I put content that doesn't match the XSD it errors out.

What do I have to do to alter ActiveMQ's redelivery policy?

Comment: @JustinBertram Yup. Will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of investigation and poking around in ActiveMQ with the debugger, I figured out what's going on. It turns out the configuration above is basically correct. I modified it slightly to:

```
<amq:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="20" useExponentialBackOff="true" 
     initialRedeliveryDelay="5000" backOffMultiplier="2" maximumRedeliveryDelay="600000"/>
```

What is confusing though is the client side AND the server are both trying to do retries, but it appears they use different algorithms:

- The client side initially makes **6** re-attempts, 1 second apart.
- If those all fail, it sends the message back to ActiveMQ
- ActiveMQ performs the redelivery behavior, which means to use the initial redelivery delay (**5** sec)
- If the messages still fail, the client again does re-tries at 1 second intervals, but this time it only makes **5** attempts.
- ActiveMQ again does redelivery behavior, doubling the delay to **10s**.
- Upon re-delivery, the client again retries, but this time only **4** times before sending the message back to ActiveMQ.

This cycle keeps going, with the client reducing the number of local retries by 1 each time, and ActiveMQ increasing the retry time using exponential backoff. Finally, ActiveMQ sends the message at 10 minute intervals (the maximum delay), with the client doing 0 local retries on failures. I guess the idea in the client is to try to let the code solve the problem locally a few times, but it figures over time this becomes decreasingly likely.